# Laravel eloquent -getting user info based on id, for each comment in a query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an API endpoint where I am suppose to send all the relevant data for articles. I have tables `users`, `comments`, `articles`. `Users` table has fields `id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, table `comments` has fields `id`, `article_id`, `user_id`. Relationships are defined like this:

Article model:

```
public function comments()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
  }
```

User model:

```
public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
```

Comment model:

```
public function user()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
  }
```

Now in my function I am getting articles and then creating an array with info about comments. I should get user `first_name`, and `last_name` for each comment, but I am not sure how to do this and if it is possible to do it when getting a collection from eloquent query?

This is the function:

```
$result = Article::where('publish', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15);

    foreach($result as $article){
      $articles[$article->id] = $article;
      $articles[$article->id]['comments'] = $article->comments()->get();
    }

    return $articles;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you have defined the relationships use it like :

```
$article = Article::with('comments.user')->where('publish', '1')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15);
```

now in your view do like this :

```
@foreach($article->comments as $comment)
     {{$comment->body}} by {{$comment->user->name}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this is an API so I am sending json data, and I can't do that in the view.

Comment: even if you are sending it as json you will get objects, once you have the first line in your controller i.e $article = //rest of the code here do a return $article in the controller and you will see the output which can be iterated over

Comment: Oh, yes of course, I missed the part with('comments.user') , great, thank you!